# how can i log in to my Instagram account without the confirmation code sent to my phone?

Tags: account-recovery, instagram

I'm having troubles trying to log in to my Instagram account. I have my email available and my Instagram account linked to my Facebook. The problem is when I try to log in, it keeps asking me for a confirmation code that they sent to an old number I used to have when I was living in Argentina. Now I live in Chile, my old phone just died, so I bought a new one, and then all this happened. I have my Instagram backup codes, but it won't recognize them (it says they're wrong even though I've used only one of them). I've tried everything, I even sent thousands of help requests and they keep sending me the same email with a shortcut to get to my Instagram account, plus they keep asking me for the phone confirmation (so it doesn't work at all).
Help, please!